# running pytorch geometric get CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED when calling `cublasCreate(handle)`

Tags: pytorch

I am running the code in this notebook.
https://colab.research.google.com/github/zaidalyafeai/Notebooks/blob/master/Deep_GCN_Spam.ipynb#scrollTo=UjoTbUQVnCz8
I get an error when I change the data set to my own data set. I know this might be an error of my code. Then I cleared all the code to generate data sets. I saved the two data sets as file and reload it. I really cannot see the difference between these two data sets.

The shape and type of these two data sets is provided below. I can provide any information that is needed. Can anyone help me fix this?

This is my data set

```
data = torch.load("dataset.pt")
data
>>>Data(edge_attr=[3585, 1], edge_index=[2, 3585], x=[352, 1], y=[352])
data.x.dtype, data.y.dtype, data.edge_attr.dtype, data.edge_index.dtype
>>>(torch.float32, torch.int64, torch.float32, torch.int64)
data.edge_index.T.numpy().shape
>>>(3585, 2)
np.unique(data.edge_index.T.numpy(), axis=0).shape
>>>(3585, 2)
np.unique(data.edge_index.T.numpy(), axis=0).shape
>>>(3585, 2)
data.edge_index.unique().shape
>>>torch.Size([352])
data.edge_index
>>>tensor([[ 13,  13,  13,  ..., 103, 103, 103],
           [  1,   2,   3,  ...,   6,   9,  10]])
```

This is the data set mentioned in the notebook

```
data2 = torch.load("spam.pt")
data2
>>>Data(edge_attr=[50344, 1], edge_index=[2, 50344], x=[1000, 1], y=[1000])
data2.x.dtype, data2.y.dtype, data2.edge_attr.dtype, data2.edge_index.dtype
>>>(torch.float32, torch.int64, torch.float32, torch.int64)
data2.edge_index
>>>tensor([[  0,   1,   1,  ..., 999, 999, 999],
           [455, 173, 681,  ..., 377, 934, 953]])
```

Python version: 3.8

PyTorch geometric version: 1.6.2

CUDA version: 10.2

System: Windows 10

[Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vobS0.png)

Comment: please don't post screenshots of code but insert it as text formatted as code.

Comment: For people searching this in the future, I changed the kernel_size in SplineConv layer. It gives no error any more. The kernel size I tried is all 1 or like 3, 11 in the last several layers. I don't know why is this. I might give an answer while I become more familiar with this.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I need to make sure that my edge_attributes where in the range of [0,1].

See [here](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric/issues/716#issuecomment-537475199)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27647787)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It's not link-only because "In my case, I need to make sure that my edge_attributes where in the range of [0,1]" is an answer.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Maybe you're right, but that is not how I read the _"In my case, ..."_, which I read more like _"I don't know if it is also your problem, but read this link for more info"_.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That would make the answer wrong, not very low quality, though. See: [Are blatantly wrong answers very low quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality)